# How to install a minimal cuda driver file into Alpine linux

Tags: docker, cuda, alpine-linux

I'm wanting to install the minimal cuda runtime files into alpine linux and create a much smaller docker base with cuda than that provided by nvidia themselves.  The nvidia official ones are enormous as usual.

How do I obtain these runtime files without pulling the entire cuda 8 toolkit during docker build?

Comment: I don't know so much about cuda. Isn't this useful? https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/

Comment: @Robert - not really.  They do what they always do - download a big install file containing the full toolkit and bloat the result.  It's frustrating that NVIDIA want you to install so much junk.  They really haven't considered deployment properly in my opinion.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Do you know what exactly you need from that image? Selectively speaking. You can use docker multi-stage build to keep only what you need from a given previous image. (Dockerfile with multiple FROM)

Comment: @Robert - my aim is to get a fairly small end image.  I could in theory just copy the shared objects, but it's a bit messy.  I would like to be able to download the drivers and extract the minimum needed.  I'm wanting to create something that is easy to maintain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com , it's too far from a question about programming.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak as to what other files might be needed. However, Nvidia drivers are compiled with `glibc`, and alpine uses `musl-libc` to maintain its small footprint. You would likely need the nvidia driver's [source code](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/opensource) so you could recompile it with `musl`, or an alpine baseimage that implements `glibc` such as [this one](https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-glibc). I haven't tried using this yet, but I was able to sucessfully compile `libcudacore` with `musl` and `gcc/make` on an alpine 3.8 container. I have not yet been able to compile the entire Nvidia/Cuda toolkit yet. I will attempt to test this more when I have more time.

Comment: Any advance in compile of Nvidia/Cuda with musl?

Comment: D`: Unfortunately this project got sidelined for other higher priority items on my team. Sorry friends.

Answer (score 2):

somebody's solution for alpine-cuda:

https://arto.s3.amazonaws.com/notes/cuda

```
Drivers

    https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver

$ lsmod | fgrep nvidia

$ nvidia-smi

Driver Installation

    https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.77/README/
    https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-installer

Driver Installation on Alpine Linux

    https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc
    https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases
    https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs

$ apk add sudo bash ca-certificates wget xz make gcc linux-headers

$ wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/master/sgerrand.rsa.pub

$ wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.27-r0/glibc-2.27-r0.apk
$ wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.27-r0/glibc-bin-2.27-r0.apk
$ wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.27-r0/glibc-dev-2.27-r0.apk
$ wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.27-r0/glibc-i18n-2.27-r0.apk

$ apk add glibc-2.27-r0.apk glibc-bin-2.27-r0.apk glibc-dev-2.27-r0.apk glibc-i18n-2.27-r0.apk

$ /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8

$ bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.77.run --check

$ bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.77.run --extract-only

$ cd NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.77 && ./nvidia-installer

Driver Uninstallation

$ nvidia-uninstall

Driver Troubleshooting

    Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 390.77NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.77.run: line 998: /tmp/makeself.XXX/xz: No such file or directory\nExtraction failed.

    $ apk add xz  # Alpine Linux

    bash: ./nvidia-installer: No such file or directory

    Install the glibc compatibility layer package for Alpine Linux.

    ERROR: You do not appear to have libc header files installed on your system. Please install your distribution's libc development package.

    $ apk add musl-dev  # Alpine Linux

    ERROR: Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running kernel. Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they are properly configured

    $ apk add linux-vanilla-dev  # Alpine Linux

    ERROR: Failed to execute `/sbin/ldconfig`: The installer has encountered the following error during installation: 'Failed to execute `/sbin/ldconfig`'. Would you like to continue installation anyway?

    Continue installation.

Toolkit

    https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
    https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/

Toolkit Download

    https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=runfilelocal

$ wget -c https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.2/Prod2/local_installers/cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux

Toolkit Installation

    https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/

Toolkit Installation on Alpine Linux

$ apk add sudo bash

$ sudo bash cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux

# You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration. Do you wish to continue? y
# Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 396.37? y
# Do you want to install the OpenGL libraries? y
# Do you want to run nvidia-xconfig? n
# Install the CUDA 9.2 Toolkit? y
# Enter Toolkit Location: /opt/cuda-9.2
# Do you want to install a symbolic link at /usr/local/cuda? y
# Install the CUDA 9.2 Samples? y
# Enter CUDA Samples Location: /opt/cuda-9.2/samples

$ sudo ln -s cuda-9.2 /opt/cuda

$ export PATH="/opt/cuda/bin:$PATH"

Toolkit Uninstallation

$ sudo /opt/cuda-9.2/bin/uninstall_cuda_9.2.pl

Toolkit Troubleshooting

    Cannot find termcap: Can't find a valid termcap file at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/Term/ReadLine.pm line 377.

    $ export PERL_RL="Perl o=0"

    gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

    $ apk add g++  # Alpine Linux

    cicc: Relink `/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1' with `/usr/glibc-compat/lib/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `memset'

    https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/issues/58

    $ scp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 root@alpine:/usr/glibc-compat/lib/libgcc_s.so.1

    $ sudo /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /usr/glibc-compat/lib /lib /usr/lib

Compiler

    https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/

$ nvcc -V
```

Answer (score 1):

The reality is that Nvidia/CUDA is not supported in any way with Alpine Linux Musl or its libc port, and you will end up with a flaky image nevertheless even if you succeed with your alchemist venture.

Nvidia drivers and CUDA Toolkits are incredibly complex systems that honestly I can't see the point to compile it yourself for an unsupported system library or an unsupported port for libc, with all the unexpected to happen even in the case it compiles. Use Debian's slim images or Ubuntu minimal and install official supported files manually, as this is the smallest you can go. Or even better use the "huge" Nvidia DockerHub images (ubuntu LTS based).

Anyway, beyond this question, the Nvidia DockerHub ones are the best way to go, they are supported by the creators of CUDA Toolkit itself and they are no brainers. If you want to be picky go to their Gitlab's repository for dockers, you can build up Debian/Ubuntu by hand pretty easily and quick.

Yes they Nvidia DockerHub images are 1-2 gig's large, but normally you only have to download them once, as you use the image as a base, if you add your code to it only those layers of your code which are normally small to dozens of Mbi are to be recurrently pulled/pushed, **not the entire image**, so honestly I can't see a reason why people is so much concerned about image sizes, small is better no doubt but up to a point, spending your valuable time in your actual needs is far better.

Comment: Usecases for smaller images are for applications that devs want to quickly load the image in memory and thus small images do have its benefits. However, in most CUDA usecase you either serving DL models in a K8s cluster, or using others serving library to orchestrate. Thus there aren't any reason to have a alpine linux image anw.

Comment: @AaronPham exactly. Normally the best way to go is to install a cluster of cards and provide an interface for the actual application (small and slick) to use it.

Comment: It's been a bit more than a few years now but I actually did manage to get a fully functioning version with cuda.  But, I never documented it publicly so I can't tell anyone how I did it exactly. Doh!

Answer (score -1):

Please define what you actually mean by "into Alpine Linux".

Regardless whether you're running the workloads directly on the host or in a container or chroot - you need to install the whole NVidia driver stack (including Cuda libs, kernel drivers, etc) on the *host*. Also kernel and userland drivers are two sides of the same product, both have to have the same version.

This means: whatever the host OS actually is, it has to be exactly one of those directly supported by NVidia. You have to use exactly the kernel versions (and configurations) that Nvidia built their proprietary/binary-only drivers for. Using a different kernel version or recompiling it with different configuration **MIGHT POSSIBLY** work, but it's **DANGEROUS**. Even with exactly the officially supported distros, it's still gambling, and depending on moon phase or whether some Chinese rice bag fallen over. It often works, but when it doesn't anymore, you're most likely out of luck.

Now when you're putting your workloads into some separate OS image, e.g. chroot or container, you also have to have the *same* driver package version in that image, too. One of the ***primary*** reasons for using containers or chroots - isolating and decoupling applications from host OS (so you don't need to fit them in anymore and do upgrades independently, even have container images independent from the host OS) - is now immediately voided. Host and workload need to fit together exactly.

In short: if you wanna have a CUDA workload, both host OS as well as workload image (container, chroot, etc) need to be supported by that, and they both need to have the same driver version installed. Anything else is just russian roulette.

Since somebody mentioned "nvidia-docker". This breaks the security isolation that docker is originally meant for. (just look at the source, which actually is available somewhere on github). It's nothing but a better chroot. And still, host and docker image need to have the *same* driver stack version installed.

Finally, I'd like to ask the question, what your actual use case is here.

Be warned: this all might be okay for playing games on an totally unimportant home computer, but really not suited for anything professional, where stability and security matter. If you're bound to certain data security / privacy regulations like GDPO, keep far away from this - you just cannot comply to these regulations with those proprietary drivers. Legally dangerous.

--mtx

Addendum: why do proprietary kernel drivers never work reliably ?
Express answer: the Linux kernel was never ever made for that, this just isn't supported.

Longer answer: kernel modules are NOT external programs, that are executed in  some isolated environment (like eg. done with userland programs) - they are (by definition) integral pieces of the kernel that just happen to be lazily loaded when needed. (they are not even like shared libraries / DLLs). This means that they have to fit - on binary level - exactly to the actual build of the kernel you're running. When compiling the kernel, there're lots of config options that influence the actual internal binary layout in subtle ways, e.g. enabling/disabling some features can change the layout of certain data structures, cpu specific optimizations can change datastructures, calling conventions, locking mechanisms, and much much more.
And those things also change from kernel version to another. We're e.g. doing lots of internal refactorings (e.g. in data structures, macros and inline functions) after which the same piece source code generates very different binary code.

Therefore, any kernel modules always need to be compiled exactly for a specific kernel image (with the same config options, against the same includes, with the same compiler flags), or you risks horrible failures that could lead to lockups, security flaws, data corruptions or even total data loss.

You have been warned.

Comment: Docker container running Alpine Linux.  I got it part of the way with alpine but ended up using a customized debian image instead

Answer (score -2):

**To clarify, this is just the driver. Not cuda. That's another story.**

In fact this turns out to be much easier than expected.  I just didn't quite /understand how far nvidia-docker project had come and quite how it worked.

Basically, download and install the latest nvidia-docker. From the nvidia-docker project.

https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/releases

Then create an alpine linux Dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:3.5
LABEL com.nvidia.volumes.needed="nvidia_driver"
ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

RUN /bin/sh
```

Build it.

```
docker build -t alpine-nvidia
```

Run

```
nvidia-docker run -ti --rm alpine-nvidia
```

Note the use of the nvidia-docker cli instead of the normal docker cli.

`nvidia-docker` calls docker cli with extra parameters.

Comment: Could you explain how you are using this alpine image?
Do you go ahead and install cuda on the container? I'm really confused because I think you need cuda there to be able to run anything. Also the volumes mounted by nvidia-docker do provide a `nvidia-smi` file in the container but it does not actually run (binary was not compiled for alpine I guess). Isn't that an issue?

Comment: The project had taken a back seat for a while.  They work but with some other unrelated issues. Mileage may vary...

Comment: I tried your minimal example and `nvidia-smi` refuses to run on my container. I understand maybe you did not get to actually deploy this, thanks anyway.

Comment: Because some things are missing.  nvidia-smi is probably compiled against the stdc lib.  Alpine doesn't use that.  It uses a different one.   I didn't say there wouldn't be pain.

Comment: To clarify,  this is just the driver.  Not cuda.  That's another story.

Comment: I went down this path a while ago once... and compiled some nvidia drivers with musl. that project also took the back seat D`: Somehow I find myself again on the hunt for this functionality. I'll post here when I find out